# How to install SQL Server Driver for PHP for use with WampServer 2.0i?

Tags: windows, sql-server, php

I am using WampServer 2.0i (PHP 5.3.0 and Apache 2.2.11) on Windows* and would like to connect to SQL Server 2008. I downloaded the [SQL Server Driver for PHP 1.1 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ccdf728b-1ea0-48a8-a84a-5052214caad9) which provides an assortment of driver DLL's.

The chart I am provided with in the help files is:

```
Driver file                  PHP version    Thread safe?    Use with PHP .dll
===========                  ===========    ============    =================
php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc6.dll    5.3            no              php5.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll    5.3            no              php5.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll     5.3            yes             php5ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll     5.3            yes             php5ts.dll
```

Further instructions say:

> If the name of the driver file contains "vc9", it should be used with a PHP version compiled with Visual C++ 9.0. If the name of the driver file contains "vc6", it should be used with a PHP version compiled with Visual C++ 6.0.

How am I supposed to know which version of Visual C++ was used to compile PHP? I realize on a Unix distro I'd have more intimate knowledge of this because I'd likely be installing PHP and Apache separately and compiling them (it's been ages since I've done so).

Should I even try to install this driver dll, or is there some better way to get PHP to talk to SQL Server?

**Windows 7 Professional 64-bit; SQL Server 2008; WampServer 2.0i*

Comment: I found this post at [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldriverforphp/thread/55268c68-9d37-4b0f-ad0e-4213bad1d182): *"PHP dropped support in 5.3 for the mssql.dll...it sucked anyway.  However, you can use Microsoft's driver 1.1 for the 5.3 php build, but you will have to modify your php files to reference the sqlsrv_ function set instead of mssql_."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [forum post at wampserver.com](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,65174):

> php used in wamp is vc6
>
> wamp 2.0 is not built in VC++ at all

Looking in the `wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\` folder, I found `php5ts.dll` so I will assume I need to use the thread safe version.

So, if I am right, the answer is to use the `php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll` driver.

Also I'll be attempting to modify the `wamp\wampmanager.ini` file to have the dll show up in the extension list from the wampserver tray icon menu.